# random dice rolling game. adding up the sum of values 1,3,4,and 6 excluding 2 and 5 in python

Tags: python, list, random, counting, dice

Im trying to make a loop where I start with 5 random dice rolls. the values 1,3,4, and 6 are added up for your score, while 2s and 5s are not counted and subtract the combined amount of dice rolled with 2s and 5s from the amount of dice rolled the next turn. I can't quite figure out how to get the sum of only the dice that rolled 1,3,4,6 and roll a lesser amount of dice the next turn based off ho many dice were 2 or 5

```
#Stuck in the Mud Dice Game

Exit = 0
Rolls = int(5)
score = 0
def RollDice():
    totalsum = 0
    for die in range(0, Rolls):
        number = random.randint(1,6)
        print("die", die + 1, ":", number)
        totalsum += number
    print("score: ", totalsum) 
    
    

def Menu():
    print("1. Roll Dice")
    print("2. Exit Program")
    print()
    choice = int(input("Enter option here: "))

    if(choice == 1):
        RollDice()
    if(choice == 2):
        Exit()
Menu()
```

Comment: routine Exit() isn't defined in the code example, variable Exit, in turn, isn't used anywhere, as well as the variable score. If these variables and functions aren't important for your problem, please leave them out of the example to keep it minimal ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the for-loop, use an if statement:

```py
if number==2 or number==5:
    Rolls -= 1
else:
    totalsum += number
```

I suppose that you also need to start your function `RollDice` like this:

```py
def RollDice():
    global Rolls
    ...
```

otherwise, it might only locally (i.e., within the function) assign a new value to the variable.

---

Or do you mean the number of Rolls should be different when you re-start the program? This can only be done by writing the value to a file.

Comment: the game starts with 5 dice rolls. so 5 random dice rolls and taking only the dice that roll 1,3,4,6 to add for a score, all dice that rolled 2 or 5s are not added to the score and however many dice were 2 or 5 are not rolled the next turn. so if I rolled two 2's and one 5 I would only roll 2 dice the next turn.

Comment: Yes, but is the next "turn" still part of the running program, or do you mean you run it, then it's done, then you restart it?

Comment: yes its part of the running program. the loop will run until you've rolled and all the dice landed on either a 2 or 5 making them unroll-able

Comment: Ok, could you also show this part in your code example then? Because the way that it looks now is that you just roll 5 dice and then the program's over.